# Google Spreadsheets sum only shown rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Is it possible to sum a range of cells while ignoring rows which are not hidden?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible via formula's or Google Apps Script. See this Q&A on [so]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6793805/1536038. Please follow the feature request and star it !!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you necessarily require a Google Apps Script solution; the tags you have used suggest that a spreadsheet formula might be adequate. If this is the case, then it is definitely possible to achieve this using [SUBTOTAL](http://googledocs.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/tips-tricks-using-new-subtotal-function.html).

For example:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,A:A)
```

will sum all cells in column A that are not hidden. `109` is the [`function_code`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649) which consists of 9 for SUM, prepended with 10 so hidden values will be skipped.

Your question requests that the sum should be "ignoring rows that are not hidden", which, I believe, is equivalent to "sum the hidden rows". This may be achieved using:

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUBTOTAL(109,A:A)
```

Comment: Where can the reference be found regarding the `function_code` argument? I've learned something today !! Thanks for that.

Comment: Unfortunately the Google Docs documentation leaves something to be desired (the links within that blog post used to work). In this case I think it would be reasonably safe to rely on the Excel documentation: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx

Comment: Documentation for SUBTOTAL (including `function_code`) can be found at [Google Docs Help Center](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649).

Comment: @pnuts that is indeed how the OP reads literally. Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its not possible (for now).

Feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=195

Comment: It is according to [SUBTOTAL docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649).